# How i can show 3 Toasts with delay of 1 second for each

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I want to show `Toast` 3 times with delay of 1 second for each and after 3rd toast my game is start again.

here is my code through this toast shows only one time for 3 seconds then my game start again.

```
    toast = new Toast(this);
    TextView textView=new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText("Game will be start again in 3 seconds");
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);

    toast.setView(textView);

// Here is the dialog when i press "NO" button then toast appear for 3 seconds just one's.


 alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // dialog.cancel();
                        // GamePanel.thread.resume();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        timer  = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                toast.show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                toast.cancel();

                                GamePanel.thread.setRunning(true);

                            }

                        }.start();

                        return;
                    }
                }

        );
        alertDialog.show();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // show toast 1

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // show toast 2.
        }
    }, 3000);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // show toast 3.
        }
    }, 6000);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            //  Init game.
        }
    }, 7000);
```

Comment: thanks can you edit my code and show me how its work

Comment: thanks alot can you tell me one more thing. My game is start before last toast appear how i can solve it.??

Comment: Delay the game with one more postDelayed, just set to 7000 or more.

Comment: Thanks buddy i got it

Comment: OMG! So, if you need to count down by 10, you need 11 handlers?

Comment: Just a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: In my case i need to count down by 3 so thats why i use this approach. if you have better solution then share it.